# Ignore an error with Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Is there a way to ignore an error with Jest?

I have an receive an error while importing a package and want to ignore the error so I can test the rest of my code.

Answer (score 3):

in your test file add this outside the jest `test` or `describe`

`console.error = jest.fn()`

basically it will make jest mock the console.error function so it will pass the test.

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems like jest handles error and prints it without using console.error

Answer (score 1):

You should add `transformIgnorePatterns` to your package.json:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!react-native|*put library here*)"
  ]
 },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not ignore my error. Thanks for your answer still.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined 
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/index.js:472:842) `
 and this error does not pop when I run the application

Comment: What are you passing into renderer.create()?

Comment: `<Provider store={store}>
      <Guides {...props} />
    </Provider>`and my component `Guides` import the package

Comment: I'm having the same problem with different 3rd party component. However it throws only (console) warn, not an error and therefore the tests pass. Maybe you should raise an issue at `react-native-snap-carousel`?

Comment: This is the right solution. I had a material UI error that was failing my service test (unrelated to UI), and I needed to log the error but still pass the test! And it worked! I added to `jest.config.js`:
 ```"transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!@material-ui)"
  ]```
I just don't know how to ignore MUI errors ONLY for the service tests.

Answer (score 0):

in my jestsetup.js , please add

```
console.error = message => {
//    throw new Error(message);
 };
```

My jestsetup.js file

```
// Make Enzyme functions available in all test files without importing
import { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
// Fail tests on any warning
 console.error = message => {
//    throw new Error(message);
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `test.skip` `it.skip`, `xit` or `xtest` instead of `test` or `it` to skip a specific test. Have a look at the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#testskipname-fn).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I still want to run the test, since it tests my component. But their is an error during an import in my component.